# Cluster authentication

Tags: ignite, gridgain

According to this documentation -> https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/advanced-security, it's said that the authentication mechanism only applies to JDBC connections.

Here is our scenario, we don't need any security per connection from client to server but, we want all clients to authenticate before entering the server topologies which will happen when doing this -> Ignition.getOrStart(CFG).

Is there any way we achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/security/authentication

You have the option of building your own security plugin as detailed in the Authorization
section of the url you mentioned: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/advanced-security#section-authorization

More info here: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/security/custom-authenticators

Comment: So there is no authentication which is open source.

Comment: @RSSAH Maybe there is *somewhere*, but neither within Apache Ignite nor GridGain Community Edition code base, as of 2020.